# Apache Solr, Require multiple of a single field while optimizing query to only hit specific indexes

Tags: java, search, solr

My data is partitioned inside solr so that when I send a request "+apple" (required apple) I only hit partition 'a' to search. 
Because of this optimization I cannot easily use boolean logic that spans all my data.

Solr query: +fruit:bananna +fruit:apple

Result: there are no fruit with both fields so i get 0 results because I am  searching the 'a' partition AND 'b' partition each with both required fields. In this case it is very unlikely that a record with the fruit field has two names, however this is a multi-valued field, so it is possible and I want those records to be at the top of my result from solr.

One way to get what I want would be to change the query to: fruit:bananna fruit:apple
However... this will sometimes return results that are neither apple nor bananna because solr marks both as optional thus I allow it to search all my indexes. For example: 
fruit:bananna fruit:apple Country:Mexico
This might return oranges in Mexico... in which case I would rather get 0 results.

Also, doing two separate queries is not an option...does anyone know of a better way to get this 'REQUIRED OR' functionality with my partition optimization?

I am also open to other designs, i'm just looking for input.

Comment: Your example `fruit:banana fruit:apple` should _not_ give any hits that doesn't contain at least one of those terms. Do you have an example where that is the case? And what is the output for those documents when you append `debug=all` to your query to get full scoring information?

Comment: You are correct. I updated my question to be more clear. But, I dont think messing with the weights will allow them to be sufficiently low to disappear entirely from the results.

Comment: If you want to express that `Country:Mexico` is required together with either `apple` or `banana`, you can express that using boolean logic: `fruit:(banana OR apple) AND Country:Mexico`. If you want at least two of the terms to be present, you can use the edismax handler with `q=mexico apple banana&mm=2` - this will give you either bananas or apples in mexico, or documents that reference both apple and bananas. You'll have to express what you mean explicitly; Solr can't infer meaning from what you're typing. You can also use `fq=Country:Mexico` to filter docs to those that match.

Comment: I took a break from this but coming back I wonder if you have any other advice. I've also clarified my predicament a little better. @MatsLindh

Comment: If you want specific search behavior, you'll have to write that behavior as a proper query - i.e. using OR and AND to indicate which combination of terms are optional and which are required. Either in your query, or by using a filter query to further filter down the documents after your main search (which in effect will AND the query to the original query, without affecting score).

Comment: So you're telling me that if I do an optional query on apple with a filter on apple AND an optional query on banana with a filter on banana AND boost by whatever else I will achieve the same thing. Ok.

Comment: So what I am now looking at would be splitting the query into two halves:
**+fruit:apple&fruit:banana&fq=fruit:apple**
here I am hitting the partition with only fruits beginning with the letter 'a'

AND a separate query of

**+fruit:banana&fruit:apple&fq=fruit:banana**

here I am hitting only the partition with fruits beginning with the letter 'b'

which I will then still have to merge myself. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Couldn't you use sharding to run the same query on both instances and get the result pre-merged back? The `fq` part relating to your original query was in relation to the country, not the fruit type. If you have the actual query as `fruit:apple fruit:banana` and `fq=country:Mexico`, and then use sharding to query both shards (the `shards` parameter), you should end up with one result, merged from the results on both shards (the "partition" part of your query changes the problem a bit, but the query itself should be the same)